# How would I get readeable text from webpage using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to navigate a webpage - https://gmet.edupage.org/. I have gotten to the login page entered the login details and entered the page where I wanna read the text and print it into console. There isnt any text I dont want I just want to print out only and only the visible text not the code. Unfortunately there is a lot of text so manually setting each element and printing the text out would take ages. So is there an easy function or way to print out only the readeable text with selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the `body` of the page and just print out the text within it using `.text`

```
txt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('browser_chrome')

print(txt.text)
```

Output:

```
Tieto stránky používajú súbory cookie na analýzu návštevnosti stránok. Informácie o používaní našich stránok sú na tento účel zdieľané so spoločnosťou Google.
Ok
PRIHLÁSENIE
GYMNÁZIUM, Metodova 2, Bratislava
Rozvrh
Známky
Písomky / DÚ
Objednávanie obedov
Menu
Aktuálne informácie
O škole
Školský rok
Informácie pre žiakov školy
Tlačivá na stiahnutie
Štúdium v zahraničí
Záujemcovia o štúdium
Projekt FinQ
Školská jedáleň
Školský psychológ
METODKA občianske združenie
Športový klub METODKA
Rada školy
Web Mail
Informácie pre verejnosť
Kontakty
Škola je zapojená
Škola získala certifikát
Naša škola získala v roku 2014 a v roku 2017 a 2020 opakovane obnovila francúzsky certifikát kvality LabelFrancEducation
VIAC »
Pondelok 12. 10. 2020
Počet návštev: 25872260
"Naše obedy"
VIAC »
Škola je zapojená
Škola je zapojená
 FinQ – PROGRAM FINANČNÉHO VZDELÁVANIA A ROZVOJA FINANČNEJ KULTÚRY PRE ŠKOLY
VIAC »
Aktuálne informácie
Aktualizácia opatrení ku dňu 1.10.2020
Usmernenie MŠVVaŠ SR k postupu škôl a školských zariadení pri realizácií výchovno vzdelávacieho procesu počas mimoriadnej situácie v súvislosti s ochorením Covid-19
Nad rámec opatrení vyplývajúcich z manuálov opatrení pre školy a školské zariadenia sa bez ohľadu na farbu semaforu predmetnej školy neodporúča realizovať:
organizáciu škôl v prírode a lyžiarskych výcvikov, a to ani dennou formou
organizácia kultúrnych, umeleckých a tanečných aktivít mimo povinného výchovno-vzdelávacieho procesu
VIAC »
Ako postupovať v jednotlivých prípadoch v súvislosti s COVID-19?
Riaditeľka školy zverejňuje pre rodičov, žiakov a učiteľov prehľad ako postupovať v jednotlivých prípadoch pri ochorení COVID-19
Ako postupovať v jednotlivých prípadoch (podozrenie, resp. pozitivita)?
Vyhlásenie zákonného zástupcu o bezinfekčnosti
Vyhlásenie návštevníka školy po súhlase riaditeľky školy
Informácie pre rodičov a žiakov školy
Riaditeľka školy si Vám dovoľuje oznámiť, že aktuálna situácia na škole v súvislosti s pandémiou COVID- 19 je nezmenená od začiatku školského roka, t.j. škola je v zelenej fáze semaforu. Výsledky testovaných žiakov a učiteľov na COVID-19, ktorí nastúpili na začiatku školského roka do školy, boli všetky k dnešnému dňu, 18.9.2020, negatívne.
Podrobné informácie k jednotlivým fázam a im prislúchajúcim opatreniam sú uvedené v „Manuáli pre stredné školy k úprave organizácie a podmienok výchovy a vzdelávania v stredných školách pre školský rok 2020/2021“ zverejnenom na stránke MŠVVaŠ SR na tomto linku: https://www.minedu.sk/stredne-skoly-aktualizovane-1692020/, ďalej len „Manuál“. Podmienky výchovy a vzdelávania na našej škole sú vždy plne v súlade s uvedeným dokumentom, aj po jeho aktualizáciách.
VIAC »
Ukáž sa! Pomôž Eliške získať grant.
Podpor svojim hlasom Elišku Klepkovú zo Septimy A, ktorá je vynikajúca atlétka, výborná žiačka, držiteľka strieborného odznaku DofE.
Bližšie informácie o Eliške a spôsobe hlasovania nájdeš na stránke:
https://www.olympic.sk/ukazsa/eliska-klepkova.
Hlasovať môžeš každý deň do 27.9.2020.
Začiatok školského roka 2020/2021
Vyučovanie začína dňa 2.9.2020.
V tento deň majú žiaci vyučovanie od 8:00 hod. do 9:30 hod. (V tento deň sa obedy v školskej jedálni nevydávajú).
Vstup žiakov do školy je od 7:00 hod. do 8:00 hod. do budovy na Metodovej aj Jelačičovej z ulice aj z dvora, celkovo cez štyri vstupy. Prichádzať môžu priebežne. Pri každom vchode bude pedagogický dozor koordinovať vstup žiakov.
Odporúčame žiakom, aby sa nezdržiavali v priestoroch pred budovami školy a dodržiavali dvojmetrové rozostupy.
Z dôvodu dodržiavania protiepidemických opatrení a odporúčaní Ministerstva školstva, vedy, výskumu a športu SR zákonný zástupca:
VIAC »
OZNAM
Úradné hodiny počas prázdnin
v termíne od 13. 07. 2020 do 21. 08. 2020
sú každú stredu od 9.00 h do 12.00 h.
Ing. Zuzana Vaterková
riaditeľka školy
Informácia pre uchádzačov o štúdium na 8GYM
Všetkým uchádzačom o 8-ročné štúdium oznamujeme, že ku dňu 7.7.2020 sú všetky miesta na prijatie obsadené na 100%.
Ing. Zuzana Vaterková, riaditeľka školy
Kontakt
GYMNÁZIUM
Metodova 2
821 08 BRATISLAVA
+421 2 50 10 24 11
Fotogaléria
```